# Dynamic page description content from database using Symfony

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

What I hope to do is to change the content of description pages of site dynamically in database, for now the description page is loaded from yml file using `sonata.seo.page` like this :

```
//sonata_seo.yml

page:
    default: sonata.seo.page.default
    separator: ' | '
    title: Name_site
    metas:
        name:
            keywords: some keyword....
            description: "this description stored in dataabse??"
```

I called it like this `{{ sonata_seo_metadatas() }}`

So I can change it anytime in admin dashboard of site, any idea?

Comment: Did you read the usage section of the docs? https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataSeoBundle/en/3.x/reference/usage/

Comment: @bechir yea but is not too clear how to use the code to get that from database, have something to clarify?

Comment: You can easily create a `SeoConfig` entity which will contain your dynamic configuration (being edited in your admin panel) and store it in the database. Inject that config it at runtime in the service container thanks to Symfony Events.

Comment: You can also edit the title of each post in your controller without Events.

Comment: @bechir No I need to change it in the head of all pages but stored in database, you have some code...

Comment: Yeah it will be changed in all pages when you use Events. Show me what you tried to do.

Comment: @bachir yes I created a table in database `seo_content`with title of page and then get the value in controller and then in head of twig thats all?

Comment: Yeah you can try it and show the code.

Comment: @bachir now I created entities and table of title page in database the problem is how to use service to get data from database and alter all this value at runtime

Comment: Show me what you tried to do